# How to Declare, Populate and Use a Variable using Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, variables

I swear this has been asked so many times previously, yet I cannot seem to apply other examples to my use case:

First things first, this query will be executed as part of an Informatica SQL Source Qualifier, and in some circumstances, be passed-through from an SQL Server OpenQuery statement, so please be mindful of this, and
that SQL Plus will not be used be used; Oracle SQL Developer is used only for code development.

My history is primarily SQL Server & Teradata, but as the title suggests, I now have a requirement where I need to declare, populate and use a variable in Oracle, all within the same procedure. *Not SP, so no In/Out declarations*

In SQL Server, this code will work as expected (line numbers added for clarity):

```
1.  Declare @MaxDate Int
2.
3.  With f_data (cal_period) As (Select 201904 As cal_period)
4.
5.  Select @MaxDate = Max(cal_period) From f_data
6.
7.  Select
8.  Case
9.      When (@MaxDate%100) < 12 Then @MaxDate+1
10.     Else (@MaxDate+100) - ((@MaxDate%100)-1)
11. End As dt
```

- Line 1: These are YYYYMM date periods defined as int
- Line 3: I am using an inline view (CTE) here for illustration, and to
  make it easier for you to copy and paste, but in reality, this is
  actually a physical control table, so would not normally be visible in the
  script.
- Line 5: Populates the parameter (SQL Server prefixes parameters with
  the at symbol) with the single-value resultset
- Line 7-11: Is simply the logic to progress the period by one, the
  percentage-mark in SQL Server is the Modulus function, Oracle is
  written as Mod(@MaxDate,100)

For those unfamiliar with SQL Server, it does not need a reference table such as Dual ("Sys.Dual") in order to execute the query, such that for Oracle a "From Dual" statement is necessary on the missing Line 12

My requirement is essentially a carbon-copy of the above T-SQL, so I need to declare a one-time use variable, to populate that variable with the results of an SQL query, and then to use this variable in a transformation - the result of which is captured to an Informatica and SSIS variable for later use.

So far, I have tried declaring a variable, this seemed to work (by which I mean it didn't return an error):

```
Declare MaxPeriod Int;
Begin
    Select 201904 Into MaxPeriod From Dual;
End;
```

And populating from an SQL statement is also showing as successfully completed:

```
Declare MaxPeriod Int;
Begin
    Select Max(MaxPeriodVal) Into MaxPeriod From CtrlTable;
End;
```

Although I can't seem to get beyond this to actually test the variable as put.line statements fail, as do simple Case checks:

```
Declare MaxPeriod Int;
Begin
    Select 201904 Into MaxPeriod From Dual;
End;


Select
Case
    When 201904 = MaxPeriod Then 'Match'
    Else 'No Match'
End As dteChk
From Dual;
```

I have attempted to prefix the MaxPeriod in the check with a colon, and, to have prefixed,suffixed/both with an ampersand eg :MaxPeriod; &MaxPeriod; MaxPeriod&; &MaxPeriod&
All of which failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic issue is a variable scope problem. You're declaring `MaxPeriod` within the context of a PL/SQL anonymous block, so it will disappear (fall out of scope) when the block ends on line 4.

You could put your entire query inside the PL/SQL block, but there's not an easy way to return an entire result set from a PL/SQL block, so I don't think you want that.

I don't know how your Oracle driver handles native queries, but this might work:

```
var MaxPeriod number; -- bind variable declared as global scope for this script

Begin -- one of several ways to assign values to bind variables
    :MaxPeriod := 201904;
End;
/

Select
Case
    When 201904 = :MaxPeriod Then 'Match'
    Else 'No Match'
End As dteChk
From Dual;
```

If the `var` syntax doesn't work for you to declare a SQL bind variable, then you may have to look into some other way of passing a bind variable for the query string. You could probably pass a null value (for a number datatype, anyway) and then overwrite it in the SQL script.

Alternately, in your original example code, I think I'd use a CTE or an inline view instead of a variable anyway.

```
With f_data As (Select 201904 As cal_period from dual)
Select
Case
      When Mod(MaxDate,100) < 12 Then MaxDate+1
     Else (MaxDate+100) - (Mod(MaxDate,100)-1)
End As dt
from (Select Max(cal_period) as MaxDate From f_data) mp
```

Comment: Yes, whilst this doesn't explicitly resolve the problem so my not be suitable for others, variables are the natural order in cases like this such that I didn't think to just use a derived table as you have suggested in your second idea.
This I can say will absolutely work in my case although I can't test atm (at home).

Nb, you are also correct with the bind variable, being hard-coded, this will not resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substitution` variable using `define` in sql*plus as following.

```
Define MaxPeriod := 201904
Select
Case
    When &MaxPeriod = MaxPeriod Then 'Match'
    Else 'No Match'
End As dteChk
From Dual;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank-you for your response Tejash however, I did stipulate at the beginning that SQL*plus will not be used here, and, I think you have misunderstood the requirement, as you have simply hardcoded the value during the bind, rather than populating using the resultset of another query as demonstrated.